VS Code workspaces settings for array value not merged properly
I have my user settings for pylint as
  "pylint.args": [
    "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
    "--disable=missing-function-docstring",
    "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
    "--disable=pointless-string-statement",
    "--disable=invalid-name",
    "--diable=redefining-outer-name",
    "--max-line-length=120"
  ],

I wanted to change the line length for one particular workspace to 80, so I added that to .vscode/settings.json
  "pylint.args": [
    "--max-line-length=80"
  ],

I expected it to merge the max-line-length value into the users.settings json, but it simply reset the entire pylint.args array.
Is there a way of changing only one value of a settings that is an array in your workspace settings, and have the array automatically merged?
